# Geb Exception in Groovy

Tags: groovy, geb

I am getting the following exception

```
    geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException at ApprovalChannelSpec.groovy:40
    Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.powerassert.PowerAssertionError at   ApprovalChannelSpec.groovy:40
```

A more details can be found below:
![1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJXGF.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you have a condition that did not happen within the allotted time. In your case it looks like it is waiting for 45 seconds for the invoices link tab to be present, but it never shows up.

The docs for the `waitFor` method specify this http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.0/api/geb-core/geb/waiting/Wait.html#waitFor(groovy.lang.Closure):

> Invokes the given block every retryInterval seconds until it returns a
>   true value according to the Groovy Truth. If block does not return a
>   truish value within timeout seconds then a WaitTimeoutException will
>   be thrown. If the given block is executing at the time when the
>   timeout is reached, it will not be interrupted. This means that this
>   method may take longer than the specified timeout. For example, if the
>   block takes 5 seconds to complete but the timeout is 2 seconds, the
>   wait is always going to take at least 5 seconds.
>
> If block throws any Throwable, it is treated as a failure and the
>   block will be tried again after the retryInterval has expired. If the
>   last invocation of block throws an exception it will be the cause of
>   the WaitTimeoutException that will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I am a newbie in Geb!

Answer (score 0):

You need use `waitFor`

Look this docs: [waiting](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/javascript.html#waiting)

p.s. Yes, @jeff-story right.

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun ok, no problem)